# Getting response From Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

When trying to get the responseText from an ajax call built in plain vanilla javascript, Firebug seems to see the request but one cannot get a reference to the responseText.

This is the code for function

```
function getAjaxResponse(){    
    var ajaxObj = getAjaxObj();
    ajaxObj.open('get', 'responsePage.php', true);
    ajaxObj.onReadyStateChanged = function(){
        if(ajaxObj.readyState == 4
            && ajaxObj.status == 200){
                //no functions are getting fired in here                
                //this does not get logged to console
                console.log(ajaxObj.responseText);
                //neither does this
                console.log(2);
        }
    };
    ajaxObj.send(null);

   //this does gets logged to console
   console.log(1);
}
```

function for the ajax object

```
function getAjaxObj(){
    var req;  
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        try{
            req = new XMLHttpRequest();                                                                 
        } catch(e){
            req = false;
        } finally {
            return req;
        }
    } else {
        if(window.ActiveXObject){
            try{
                req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e){
                try{
                    req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml.XMLHTTP");
                } catch(e){
                    req = false;
                } finally {
                    return req;
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also here is the view from firebug
[image]

How to get a reference to the response from the ajax call?

Comment: Have a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnReadyStateChanged` needs to be `onreadystatechange`.  JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Haha.. thanks so much was getting well p!#$#d.  Will accept your answer as soon as it will let me! cheers

Answer (score 1):

`ajaxObj.onReadyStateChanged`: `onreadystatechange` should all be lower case (and without the trailing 'd')